# Master forest on host-1, replicas on other remaining hosts in ml-gradle?

Tags: marklogic, ml-gradle

I have configured 5 node cluster lets say (h1, h2, h3, h4, h5)

I want to create a database `content` with one forest `content-1` on `h1` and 4 replicas on `h2,h3,h4,h5`.

Is this possible by using some ml-gradle property or I have to define custom json for the same?

[image]

`-r-` specifies replica.

Comment: Four replicas seems like overkill. That's a lot of additional overhead and storage. You typically won't have a need for that many.

Comment: In the question I have mentioned content DB but in actual I am doing it for `schemas` and `triggers` DB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the instructions at https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/Creating-forests.

It sounds like you'd want `mlForestsPerHost=content,1`  and `mlDatabaseNamesAndReplicaCounts=content,4`.

Comment: `mlForestsPerHost=content,1` and `mlDatabaseNamesAndReplicaCounts=content,4` this config is not working. output is 1 forest on each node and 4 replicas on search node.

Comment: I think I understand now - you only want one primary forest total, correct? Try setting mlDatabasesWithForestsOnOneHost=content.

Comment: `mlDatabasesWithForestsOnOneHost` this one does the job. Thanks.